# why pThread exit causes main process termination?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm testing based on linux 2.6.21 and pThread library. 
I tried several cases in order to find out workaround how to avoid main process termination. But, I didn't find out it. 
Please, tell me why exiting of thread function causes main process to be terminated?
Here is test code below,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <sys/msg.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <sys/signal.h>
    #include <linux/input.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    int handle = 0;
    int main_loop = 0;

    void *testThread(void *pParm)
    {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
        printf("====testThread loop %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
      }

      if (main_loop == 1){
      exit(0);
      }
      else if (main_loop == 2)
      {
        sleep(10);
        exit(0);
      }
      else if (main_loop == 3)
      {
        pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
      else if (main_loop == 4)
      {
        sleep(10);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      pthread_t pTestThread;

      int i, ret;

      if (argc == 2){
          main_loop = atoi(argv[1]);
      }
      if (argc == 3){
          main_loop = atoi(argv[1]);
          handle = atoi(argv[2]);
      }

      ret = pthread_create(&pTestThread, NULL, (void *)testThread, NULL);
      if (0 == ret){
        if (handle == 0)
          pthread_detach(pTestThread);
        printf("====Thread creation okay!\n");
      }else{
        printf("====Thread creation error!\n");
        return 0;
      }

      if (handle == 1)
      {
        printf("====pthread_join waiting\n");
        pthread_join(pTestThread, (void **)&ret);
        printf("====pthread_join ret %d\n", ret);
      }

      for (i=0; i < 20; i++)
      {
        printf("====Main loop %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
      }

      printf("====Main Exit\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

In this code, I have never seen the log of "====Main Exit" with a various combinations (argument 2nd and 3rd).

Comment: Please post a complete program (including global variables, headers), and the command line inputs you're using when it unexpectedly terminates (or - much better - remove the code that's not relevant to the unexpected termination, so there's no dependency on command line arguments).

Comment: What's the value of main_loop?

Comment: What is "pThread exit"?

Comment: I added the variables and headers. What I tested in console is below,  ./test 1         ./test 2               ./test 3                    ./test 4           ./test 1 1               ./test 2 1         ./test 3 1            ./test 4 1         But, all result is the same. That means main thread(process) has been terminated when test thread was terminated.

Answer (score 1):

> . Please, tell me why exiting of thread function causes main process
>   to be terminated?

Yes, In your thread function, you use "`exit()`",  This function can "`Terminates the process normally, performing the regular cleanup for terminating programs`."

you can see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/ for more details:

> Calling this function destroys all objects with static duration: A
>   program with multiple threads running shall not call exit (see
>   quick_exit for a similar function that does not affect static
>   objects).

So if you use `pthread_exit` instead of exit, you can see

```
====Main loop 18
====Main loop 19
====Main Exit
```

By the way,

```
ret = pthread_create(&pTestThread, NULL, (void *)testThread, NULL);
```

should be

```
ret = pthread_create(&pTestThread, NULL, testThread, NULL);
```

Comment: I mean, *technically* `(void *) testThread` isn't wrong in this example...it's just one step short of trying to change the return type of a function via casting.

Comment: The example code that I posted works well in others platforms such as arm or windows linux. But only it has a trouble in linux 2.6.21 & mips platform.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, ( assuming main_loop and handle are global )

```
 if (main_loop == 1){ // Main thread will exit for if 1st argument is 1
      exit(0);
      }
      else if (main_loop == 2) // Main thread will exit for if 1st argument is 2
      {
        sleep(10);
        exit(0);
      }
      else if (main_loop == 3) // Main thread should not exit if 3
      {
        pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
      else if (main_loop == 4)
      {
       // Main thread should not exit if 3, delay however is 10 seconds
        sleep(10);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
   // Interestingly for all other values main should run as usual
```

try running your binary as

```
 ./a.out 3 1 
 ./a.out 4 1 
 ./a.out 123 1
```

Note - 2nd argument is always 1, for execution to be sequenced.